# How to delete values with specific criteria from XML file in NOTEPAD++

Tags: notepad++, xml

I have a very large tree-like XML file, about 1 GB.

I need to delete lines `<Sample> ... </Sample>` including sublines inside `<Sample> ... </Sample>` that don't contain the value `<segmentation><![CDATA[0.11]]></segmentation>`.

For example, there are lines with the tags as follows:

```
<segmentation><![CDATA[0.11]]></segmentation>
<segmentation><![CDATA[0.25]]></segmentation>
<segmentation><![CDATA[0.61]]></segmentation>
```

In the example below, is it possible to delete all the `<Sample>` lines and sublines by keeping only `<Sample>` including sublines with the tag `<segmentation><![CDATA[0.11]]></segmentation>`?

Initial:

```
  <Sample>
    <title><![CDATA[South Park]]></title>
    <date><![CDATA[Tue, 29 Nov 2016 00:00:00 EST]]></date>
    <referencenumber><![CDATA[20983990]]></referencenumber>
    <segmentation><![CDATA[0.11]]></segmentation>
    <description><![CDATA[Some text goes here]]></description>
  </Sample>
  <Sample>
    <title><![CDATA[South Park]]></title>
    <date><![CDATA[Tue, 29 Nov 2016 00:00:00 EST]]></date>
    <referencenumber><![CDATA[20983990]]></referencenumber>
    <segmentation><![CDATA[0.25]]></segmentation>
    <description><![CDATA[Some text goes here]]></description>
  </Sample>
  <Sample>
    <title><![CDATA[South Park]]></title>
    <date><![CDATA[Tue, 29 Nov 2016 00:00:00 EST]]></date>
    <referencenumber><![CDATA[20983990]]></referencenumber>
    <segmentation><![CDATA[0.61]]></segmentation>
    <description><![CDATA[Some text goes here]]></description>
  </Sample>
```

Outcome:

```
  <Sample>
    <title><![CDATA[South Park]]></title>
    <date><![CDATA[Tue, 29 Nov 2016 00:00:00 EST]]></date>
    <referencenumber><![CDATA[20983990]]></referencenumber>
    <segmentation><![CDATA[0.11]]></segmentation>
    <description><![CDATA[Some text goes here]]></description>
  </Sample>
```

Comment: Instead of search/replace, utilize [**XSL transformation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). In Notepad++, it is supported by **XML Tools** plugin which you can find using **Plugin Manager**.

Comment: Warning: possible drive-by user. The OP has not been seen since he asked this question.